# Adding a picture from the web doesn't work on Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, images

I was trying to add an image using Google Chrome, but when I click on "Add picture" no picture is added. Actually, no Markdown markup is added to the post.

I also tried on this very site, and it doesn't work.

If that makes any difference, I am using Google Chrome "25.0.1364.97 m" running on Windows 8, and the image I am trying to add is http://www.garden-seat.co.uk/townandcountrygardener/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/slug.jpg.

Comment: Same problem.  I can neither upload from my computer, nor link from the web!

Comment: Same here, FireFox also won´t work

Comment: It's a javascript problem. When you open the popup, a single clic on it will close the gray background. When the image is uploaded, a javascript method try to remove this background which doesn't exist anymore. It then generates an error and avoid the uploaded image to be put inside the textearea. Bad commit I guess :)

Comment: @j0k is correct see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x01UI.png) and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RA5Gk.png).

Comment: Same here, not working in Chrome or FF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; well spotted. This relates to some over-zealous code that was *trying* to make it easier to close popups by clicking outside. Fixed and deploying real soon. It was not specific to any particular browser.